# Apache storm process order in bolt

Tags: grouping, apache-storm

1 I use kafkaSpout read message form KAFKA and process them in some bolts. I want to know if the bolt process data for each partition is ordered？

2 Will the same tuples are grouped into the same task if I use shuffle grouping?

Comment: I want to skip the timeout failed tuples. So I want to store the tuples' partitions and its max offset from the tuples msgId in a map. If the tuple's offset less than the offset I have stored. I will skip the tuple.  I use shuffle grouping. I afraid the failed tuple will be not send to the same task. So I gave the 2 questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. no kafka itself does not guarantee ordering across partitions
2. if you want your tuples to be grouped, you can use `fieldsGrouping` based on any field you want.